# How to add replyToUrl schema.org to Wordpress comments?

Tags: comments

I have the following code in my comments.php

```
  <div class="reply">
     <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
  </div>
```

I've tried to put the following filter, but it breaks the layout (it adds 2 lines of text/url):

```
function additemproptocommentreplylink( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['itemprop'] = 'replyToUrl';
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'additemproptocommentreplylink', 3, 10);
```

Can someone suggest how I can add that itemprop to the reply link?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead try the following replacement:

```
/**
 * Add itemprop attribute to the comment reply link
 */

add_filter('comment_reply_link', function( $html )
{
    if( false === stripos( $html, 'itemprop="' ) )
        $html = str_ireplace( '<a ', '<a itemprop="replyToUrl" ', $html ); 
    return $html;
}, 99 );
```

through the `comment_reply_link` filter. The HTML generation, of the comment reply link, only supports a given set of attributes and `itemprop` is not among them. That's why we try the replacement here instead.